# Neo4J text search through Node.Js app

Tags: node.js, neo4j, elasticsearch, cypher

There are questions like this on here, but no answers.

I need to implement a feature where the two types of nodes (labelled :Hashtags and :Statements) in my Neo4J 2.0 database can be searched by the users from my Node.Js app.

So that means the users enter something they need into a search field, click search, and get the results. A better scenario is that it's more responsive and finds possible matches on the fly.

How would you implement that?

I have some ideas, but unsure about which one to go for:

1. Each time the user makes a search, make this kind of Cypher query (not very efficient to query the database so much, I guess, and won't work for responsive results suggestions):

   MATCH (h:Hashtag{name:"user_query"}), (s:Hashtag{name:"user_query"}) RETURN h,s;
2. Install something like [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and let it handle the search (this is what the guys from [Linkurio.us](http://Linkurio.us) have done)

In the first option the .name property of those labeled nodes is, of course, indexed.

The second option seems to be more robust, but I really would like to avoid having to install extra software and having this kind of dependencies.

Maybe you know of a better solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why the first option would not be responsive?

After all the Neo4j indexing by default is using Lucene, the same as elastic search?
And with an index (or unique constraint) the lookup should be instant.

Did you actually test the performance? (Make sure to use parameters for the actual value)